# Copying Existing Access forms to a New Database

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

I am looking to copy few Access forms (from an existing database) to a new empty database and then link them to tables in a backend SQL server.
The forms I wish to copy over are currently linked to few tables in backend SQL server.I need to delink them from the existling tables and link them to new ones in the server.
I tried to import the forms to the new database and then in the design view changed the "record source" field to the source I wanted to link.But it did not work.
I looked up online for resources, but did not get any clear help.
I am a starter with databases and so a not-so-programmatically complicated approach will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: define "But it did not work."  Did you get an error?  what happened that wasn't supposed to happen, or what didn't happen that you expected to happen?

Comment: You don't mention which version of Access, nor do you mention if the 'new' tables have the same name as the 'old' tables, but for 2010 you would: (1) Open new database; (2) Import all required Forms, Modules, Queries, etc.; (3) Open 'External Data' tab; (4) Click on 'ODBC Databases'; (5) Select 'Link to the data source...'; (6) Select 'SQL Server'; (7) select required tables, etc.

Comment: Wayne , : I did exactly as u suggested , but I do not see the new data going to the table that i have connected newly.